# Try to setup Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 orderers by kafka cluster at multi hosts environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to setup Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 with 3 orderers connect to  4 kafka nodes at multi hosts environment but I found error at orderer console "broker.go:96: Failed to connect to broker e13a106f3821:9092: dial tcp: i/o timeout" . Bellow is my environments:
1. one host run peers of org1, 1 orderer, 4 kafka nodes and 3 zookeeper
2. one host run peers of org2, 1 orderer

org1 seems up normally abut I saw bellow error at the console log of orderer at org2

```
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.186722 client.go:397: client/brokers registered new broker #0 at 33be78497375:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.186739 client.go:397: client/brokers registered new broker #1 at 2339e38eee34:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.186743 client.go:397: client/brokers registered new broker #2 at fa8269a66bdc:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.186746 client.go:397: client/brokers registered new broker #3 at b5a700af19de:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.186816 client.go:154: Successfully initialized new client
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.187031 config.go:329: ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.187256 async_producer.go:584: producer/broker/3 starting up
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.187263 async_producer.go:596: producer/broker/3 state change to [open] on testchainid/0
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.506396 broker.go:96: Failed to connect to broker b5a700af19de:9092: dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.506475 async_producer.go:762: producer/broker/3 state change to [closing] because dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.506505 async_producer.go:458: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [retrying-1]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.506521 async_producer.go:468: producer/leader/testchainid/0 abandoning broker 3
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.506546 async_producer.go:663: producer/broker/3 shut down
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.606760 client.go:599: client/metadata fetching metadata for [testchainid] from broker kafka0:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.608799 config.go:329: ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.609061 async_producer.go:584: producer/broker/3 starting up
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.609085 async_producer.go:596: producer/broker/3 state change to [open] on testchainid/0
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.609103 async_producer.go:446: producer/leader/testchainid/0 selected broker 3
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.609119 async_producer.go:474: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [flushing-1]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.609131 async_producer.go:496: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [normal]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.923382 broker.go:96: Failed to connect to broker b5a700af19de:9092: dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.923406 async_producer.go:762: producer/broker/3 state change to [closing] because dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.923422 async_producer.go:458: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [retrying-2]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.923426 async_producer.go:468: producer/leader/testchainid/0 abandoning broker 3
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:52.923435 async_producer.go:663: producer/broker/3 shut down
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.023826 client.go:599: client/metadata fetching metadata for [testchainid] from broker kafka0:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.026292 config.go:329: ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.026574 async_producer.go:584: producer/broker/3 starting up
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.026604 async_producer.go:596: producer/broker/3 state change to [open] on testchainid/0
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.026622 async_producer.go:446: producer/leader/testchainid/0 selected broker 3
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.026639 async_producer.go:474: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [flushing-2]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.026651 async_producer.go:496: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [normal]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.156478 broker.go:96: Failed to connect to broker b5a700af19de:9092: dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.156501 async_producer.go:762: producer/broker/3 state change to [closing] because dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.156518 async_producer.go:458: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [retrying-3]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.156522 async_producer.go:468: producer/leader/testchainid/0 abandoning broker 3
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.156531 async_producer.go:663: producer/broker/3 shut down
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.256893 client.go:599: client/metadata fetching metadata for [testchainid] from broker kafka0:9092
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.259126 config.go:329: ClientID is the default of 'sarama', you should consider setting it to something application-specific.
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.259394 async_producer.go:584: producer/broker/3 starting up
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.259405 async_producer.go:596: producer/broker/3 state change to [open] on testchainid/0
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.259412 async_producer.go:446: producer/leader/testchainid/0 selected broker 3
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.259417 async_producer.go:474: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [flushing-3]
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.259422 async_producer.go:496: producer/leader/testchainid/0 state change to [normal]
2017-12-12 06:11:53.381 UTC [orderer/kafka] try -> DEBU 160 [channel: testchainid] Retrying every 1s for a total of 30s
[sarama] 2017/12/12 06:11:53.381897 broker.go:96: Failed to connect to broker b5a700af19de:9092: dial tcp: lookup b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

It seems orderer can not connect to kafka0 or others.

Would someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to connect to broker b5a700af19de:9092: dial tcp: lookup
>   b5a700af19de on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

It seems like DNS config wrong. you should check your configtx.yaml or /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the Following things you have done Properly.

1. Configured Docker-Swarm
2. Created Network
3. In your yaml you must use hostname instead of IP Address.
4. Make sure the environment variables properly while running your zookeeper and kafka containers.
5. -e "ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888"
6. -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181